# Where Could I Download The Optaplanner 6.3 Nightly Snapshot?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I just read about [Visualizing Vehicle Routing with Leaflet and Google Maps](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/03/10/VisualizingVehicleRoutingWithLeafletAndGoogleMaps.html) from Optaplanner blog. I want to see and try the code but couldn't get it, since everytime I tried to download it, it keep giving me 404 error.

[image]

Could anyone tell me where can I get those codes? 
Thanks and regards.

**UPDATE**: now it show a creepy evil..
[image]

Comment: Our internal jenkins has build the 0.3.0 snapshots, but for some reason, they haven't been mirrored to the exteran jenkins instance. See [https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/optaplanner/](https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/optaplanner/). Investigating why.

Comment: See [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-320) to track the status of this issue. See Ondrej's answer for a workaround.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet : I have check the link you gave me, but I can't find Ondrej's answer, there is only Michael Biarnes Kiefer answer, and it's a workaround for your internal jenkins (which I can't accessed it). Could you provide me more information about this? Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the link probably should work, you can [find the latest snapshots here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/optaplanner/optaplanner-distribution/6.3.0-SNAPSHOT/) (scroll all the way down for the newest ones). If you only want to look at the source files in `webexamples/sources`, you could probably just look in OptaPlanner's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-webexamples).

[Here's a direct link to the snapshot zip.](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=snapshots&g=org.optaplanner&a=optaplanner-distribution&v=6.3.0-SNAPSHOT&e=zip)

Comment: The github didn't give me the builded war for web-examples, it just give me the master code. I need the war to try the VRP with google maps application.

Comment: You could try building it yourself, or use the link I provided in my answer. Here is a link to [today's (Apr 17 2015) build](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/optaplanner/optaplanner-distribution/6.3.0-SNAPSHOT/optaplanner-distribution-6.3.0-20150417.061402-506.zip).